# How can I encrypt password in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, encryption, scripting, passwords, password-encryption

I have a batch file which is used to connect to a remote server.

Tha batch file contains:

> WMIC /NODE:"ip_address" /user: user_name /password: **pass_word**
>   process call create "path\abc.bat"

I want to encrypt **pass_word**.

Comment: What kind of encryption? What is the decryption support provided by the WMIC command? You wish to encrypt or just encode? Please provide more details.

Comment: I don't know whether WMIC provides any encryption/decryption support.
So just Encoding (In stead of Encryption) would do the job.

Comment: First, you need to check if WMIC even supports decoding. If yes, what kind of encoding/decoding? Is it Base 64?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582295/xor-a-string-in-a-bat-file/25583032

Comment: you can also "convert" your batch into exe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174386/how-can-a-bat-file-be-converted-to-exe-without-third-party-tools

Comment: This might help you to inline encode the password and pass as a parameter to WMIC : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046771/base64-encode-string-command-line-windows

Comment: @vijayinani - I was thinking of something like that. I will implement this and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: You can also take a look at this method using ADS [Prompt for password then save it](http://scripts.dragon-it.co.uk/scripts.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameSet&Frame=East&Src=%2Fscripts.nsf%2Fdocs%2Fbatch-prompt-password-save-it!OpenDocument%26AutoFramed)

Answer (score 3):

**Not exact answer to the question, but, as per the comments discussion and your acceptance to the alternate approach,** the below might help you to inline encode the password and pass as a parameter to WMIC:

[Base64 Encode "string" - command-line Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046771/base64-encode-string-command-line-windows)

Comment: Base64 just encode the password to base64 literals. It is not an encryption scheme as asked by @Biswajit Paul above

Comment: @Awan Biru ... Did you go thru the comments in the question? He is fine with simple encoding decoding too. So this answer. Have some time to go thru comments before deciding.

Comment: Since, original question did not changed, aren't your answer more suitable as comment instead? Your answer could misleads other readers, since encoding is not encrypting.

Comment: Have altered my answer. And moreover this is not heavily voted question to rely upon. The question is very raw to refer. You will find many such threads on sof.