# How to hide a password in a .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd like help in setting password in a batch file but without exposing password.

If I `SET password="abc123"`, I don't want abc123 to be visible in the batch file, as other people will be running the .bat file.

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated, and thanks in advance

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582295/xor-a-string-in-a-bat-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174386/how-can-a-bat-file-be-converted-to-exe-without-third-party-tools)

Comment: Not an answer, but just FYI: `set password="string"` would set the password to `"string"`, not `string`.

Comment: You can use this method [Password hidden using ADS](http://scripts.dragon-it.co.uk/scripts.nsf/docs/batch-password1!OpenDocument&ExpandSection=3&AutoFramed)

Answer (score 3):

**There is unfortunately no good solution to hide a password in batch**

Even if you `crypt` it, change it to `HEX`, hide it in an `Alternative Data Stream (ADS)` or whatever you want.

At a moment you have to test the value in your code with an `IF` test.

At this point the password, crypted or not, will be visible or `setted`in a variable that can be `echoed`.

You can also compress your BAT in a self-extracting `.EXE`, but this is very easy to crack, while the `.BAT` file have to be decompressed before you run it (in the `%temp%` folder).

So there is no way to really hide a password in a `.BAT` file

Comment: You are right and here is an example to catch files in the temporary folder ==> https://pastebin.com/raw/LGzywPCn

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method : [**Password hidden using ADS**](http://scripts.dragon-it.co.uk/scripts.nsf/docs/batch-password1!OpenDocument&ExpandSection=3&AutoFramed)

1. create and save your batch file
2. use the ECHO command to 'place' your password into an ADS attached
   to your batch file
3. use redirection to read the password from the ADS (Alternative Data
   Stream) file

Comment: Thanks for you input will try that option